# Pointing to an array inside a struct that is inside another struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct

How can I access an array / other type of data that is inside of a struct which is inside of another struct. This is what Ive tried so far and its coming out as `c` is not declared. I know I can declare `c` as `prod_t *c` but it defeats the purpose of something Im trying to do as it doesnt exist inside of the `root`(`a_t` struc).

```
typedef struct {
    char *name;
} prod_t;

typedef struct {
    prod_t *c;
} a_t;



int
main(int agrc, char **argv){
    a_t *root = malloc(sizeof(a_t));
    root->c=malloc(sizeof(prod_t));

    c->name = malloc( 5 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(c->name, "abc");

    printf("%s",root.c->name);



    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code, `c->name` is not a valid variable name. `c` is a member variable of the structure variable `root`. There is no *standalone* variable named `c`.

You can use like

```
root->c->name = malloc( 5 );
```

and

```
strcpy(root->c->name, "abc");
```

and

```
printf("%s\n", root->c->name);
```

Also, remember,

1. `sizeof(char)` is guranteed to produce `1` in `C`, so you can drop that part.
2. Once you're done using the allocated memory, you need to `free()` them.

Answer (score 1):

You have three pointers one is "enclosed" in another. So you have to write

```
root->c->name = malloc( 5 * sizeof(char));
strcpy( root->c->name, "abc");

printf("%s",root->c->name);
```

And you have to free them in the following order

```
free( root->c->name );
free( root->c );
free( root );
```

Take into account that in general you have to check whether the "outer" pointer was successfully "allocated" before allocating memory pointed to by the "inner" pointer.